# Redirect request to another server when first responded with empty response body

Tags: java, redirect, server, reverse-proxy, haproxy

I met an issue extending usage of Apache Proxy server, now it does redirect every GET request to one server, now I need to change the logic to redirect request to the server and if it does respond with empty response body I need to send the same request to another server, would be really grateful to hear an opinion(examples are welcome)  on which tools might be applicable for solving this issue? (Apache Proxy server and HAproxy do not provide such abilities or I could not find how to solve it using these tools).